# Passing iterators to templates

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

Sorry for the unclear question. I need to use the following template to sort an array of object belonging to a custom class using the insertion algorithm:

```
template<typename pointer, typename T, typename Functype>
void sort_array(pointer puntatore, T* obj, int dim, Functype pred){
    T val;
    for(int i=1; i<dim; i++){
        val=obj[i];
        for(int j=(i-1); j>=0; j--){
            if(pred(obj[j].*puntatore, val.*puntatore)){
                obj[j+1]=obj[j];
                obj[j]=val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how I can write a more general template that can accept any kind of iterator that points to an object of class `T`, not just a pointer. Writing `T obj` in parameter list gives me troubles with the variable `T val` in the assignment, which in this case would be something like `*val=obj[i]` being `val` itself an iterator. Is there any way to tell the template he has to take a generic iterator pointing to an object of class `T`(i.e. in the same way writing `T*` tells it to expect a pointer to an object of class `T`)?

**example of how i might use this template**

```
class Example{
   int first;
   int second;
};

template<typename pointer, typename T, typename Functype>
void sort_array(pointer puntatore, T* obj, int dim, Functype pred){
    T val;
    for(int i=1; i<dim; i++){
        val=obj[i];
        for(int j=(i-1); j>=0; j--){
            if(pred(obj[j].*puntatore, val.*puntatore)){
                obj[j+1]=obj[j];
                obj[j]=val;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    Example array[5]={{1,2},{2,4},{1,7},{5,3},{6,7}};

    //now i sort the elements in the array by their first element in a decreasing order
    sort_array(&Example::first, array, 5, [](int a, int b){return (a<b);});


}
```

Comment: @AmiTavory Have wrote `pointer` instead of `iterator`, sorry if that might have been confused. `puntatore` is just a pointer to a member of the class `T`, I'll add an example

Comment: That's OK. Actually googled it, and I guessed it meant "pointer" in Italian. There were pictures of fingers pointing.

Comment: @AmiTavory ahaha sorry! yes, it means pointer in italian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could take inspiration from STL implementations and provide an interface that would take a range instead of an array like below:

```
template<typename BidirectionalIterator, typename Predicate = 
  std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BidirectionalIterator>::value_type>>
void
insertion_sort(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last, 
  Predicate pred = {}) {
  if(first != last) {
    auto it = first; 
    while(++it != last) {
      auto it2 = it;
      while(it2 != first) {
        auto it3 = it2;
        --it3;
        if(pred(*it2, *it3)) {
          std::swap(*it2, *it3);
        } else {
          break;
        }
        --it2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36c9aca414b9353f)

Mind however, that you could also provide overloaded `operator<` or `operator>` for your objects for this to work with standard predicates:

```
bool
operator<(T const &A, T const &B) {
  return A.*puntatore < B.*puntatore;
}


bool
operator>(T const &A, T const &B) {
  return A.*puntatore < B.*puntatore;
}
```

Comment: @luigi Well spotted I didn't take into account empty ranges, corrected now :).